# Django and S3 direct uploads

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto3

In my project I've got configured and properly working S3 [storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) . Now I'm trying to configure direct uploads to s3 using [s3 direct](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct/tree/master/s3direct). It is working almost fine. The user is able to upload the image and it get stored in S3. The problems come when I am saving a reference in the DB to the image.

**models.py**

```
class FullResPicture(Audit):
    docfile = models.ImageField()
    picture = models.OneToOneField(Picture, primary_key=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
...
S3DIRECT_DESTINATIONS = {
    # Allow anybody to upload jpeg's and png's.
    'imgs': ('uploads/imgs', lambda u: u.is_authenticated(), ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'], 'public-read','bucket-name'),
}
...
```

**views.py**

```
#Doc file is the url to the image that the user uploaded directly to S3
#https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/imgs/picture.jpeg
fullRes = FullResPicture(docfile = form_list[1].cleaned_data['docfile'])
```

So if I look at my DB, I've got some images that works fine (those I upload using only django-storages) with a docfile value like this:

```
images/2015/08/11/image.jpg
```

When the application tries to access those images, S3 boto is able to get the image properly.

But then I've got the images uploaded directly from the user's browser. For those, I am storing the full url, so they look like this in the DB:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/imgs/Most-Famous-Felines-034.jpg
```

When the application tries to access them, I've got this exception:

```
File "/Users/mariopersonal/Documents/dev/venv/pictures/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 49, in _get_file
    self._file = self.storage.open(self.name, 'rb')
  File "/Users/mariopersonal/Documents/dev/venv/pictures/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 35, in open
    return self._open(name, mode)
  File "/Users/mariopersonal/Documents/dev/venv/pictures/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 363, in _open
    name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
  File "/Users/mariopersonal/Documents/dev/venv/pictures/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 341, in _normalize_name
    name)
SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to 'https:/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/imgs/Most-Famous-Felines-034.jpg' denied.
```

So apparently, S3 boto doesn't like the file references as full url.

For troubleshooting purpose, I tried hardcoding the value that is saved, so instead of the full url it saves only the last part, but then I've got this other exception when it tries to access the image:

```
IOError: File does not exist: uploads/imgs/Most-Famous-Felines-034.jpg
```

Anybody knows what is going wrong here? Does anybody has any working example of direct upload to s3 that stores the reference to the uploaded file in a model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is the way I fixed, in case it helps somebody else. **This solution applies** if you already have [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) working properly  [django-s3direct](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct/tree/master/s3direct) uploading the images from the client side but you cannot make them to work together.

### Use the same bucket

First thing I did was making sure that both, django-storages and django-s3direct were configured to use the same bucket. As you already have both django-storages and django-s3direct working separately, just check that both are using the same bucket. For most users, just need to do something like this:

**settings.py**

```
...
S3DIRECT_DESTINATIONS = {
    # Allow anybody to upload jpeg's and png's.
    'imgs': ('uploads/imgs', lambda u: u.is_authenticated(), ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'], 'public-read', AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME),
}
...
```

Note that we are using `AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`, which should be defined for django-storages configuration.

In my case was little more complex as I am using different bucket for different models.

### Store only the key

When using s3-direct, once the user has uploaded the image and submit the form, our view will receive the url where S3 has placed the image. If we store this url, when s3-storages tries to access the image, it won't work, so what we have to do is store only the file's key.

The file's key is the path to the image inside the bucket. E.g, for the **url** `https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/uploads/imgs/Most-Famous-Felines-034.jpg` the **key** is `uploads/imgs/Most-Famous-Felines-034.jpg` so that is the value we need to store on our model. In my case I'am using this snippet to extract the key from the url:

```
def key_from_url(url, bucket):
    try:
        indexOf = url.index(bucket)
        return url[indexOf:]
    except:
        raise ValueError('The url provided does not match the bucket name')
```

Once I made those changes, it worked seamlessly.
I hope this helps anybody in the same situation.

Comment: I ran into an issue where django-storages and django-s3direct were using `AWS_ENDPOINT_URL` differently. I kept that constant to set django-s3direct, but I subclassed `s3boto3storages` in order to set the `endpoint_url` class variable so that django-storages would work correctly. The problem was that django-storages was prepending the bucket name to my keys, so that django-storages was looking in `<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<key>` for items instead of `<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>`.